# Writing a sorting query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as below:

```
Job    Quantity Status
-----------------------
1      100      OK
2      400      HOLD
3      200      HOLD
4      450      OK
5      300     
6      500
```

I would like my result to be shown as below:

```
Job  Quantity Status
----------------------
4      450      OK
2      400      HOLD
1      100      OK
3      200      HOLD
6      500 
5      300
```

I have created this query but it's not working when the table contains data where the `status` column is null/empty

```
SELECT 
    Job, 
    Quantity, 
    Status 
FROM 
    myTable
ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN QUANTITY >= 400 AND STATUS = 'OK' THEN 1 
    WHEN QUANTITY >= 400 AND STATUS = 'HOLD' THEN 2 
    WHEN QUANTITY <  400 AND STATUS = 'OK' THEN 3 
    WHEN QUANTITY >= 400 AND STATUS = 'HOLD' THEN 4 
    WHEN QUANTITY >= 400 AND STATUS = '' THEN 5 
    WHEN QUANTITY <  400 AND STATUS = '' THEN 6 
END
```

Comment: Check for IS NULL instead of '' and see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless I'm misreading, I feel like you've answered your own question. You need to account for when your data is `NULL`.

The important part is that `NULL` is of a different type than `''`. Just like `'' = 0` is false, so is `NULL = ''`. `NULL` is used to represent vacuous values. Think about it in terms of boolean values instead of string. Obviously there are times where something is neither true nor false, this is where a value like `NULL` would come in. Similarly, if you think of strings as pure data instead of characters and words then there is a difference between the empty value and no value at all.

For more information, see http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_null_values.asp

So I think your code should look like:

```
SELECT Job, Quantity, Status 
    FROM myTable
ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN QUANTITY >= 400 AND STATUS = 'OK' THEN 1 
    WHEN QUANTITY >= 400 AND STATUS = 'HOLD'  THEN 2 
    WHEN QUANTITY < 400 AND STATUS = 'OK'  THEN 3 
    WHEN QUANTITY >= 400 AND STATUS = 'HOLD'  THEN 4 
    WHEN QUANTITY >= 400 AND (STATUS = '' OR STATUS IS NULL)  THEN 5 
    WHEN QUANTITY < 400 AND (STATUS = '' OR STATUS IS NULL)  THEN 6
END
```

Unless you explictly set the STATUS to `''`, you might be able to just use `STATUS IS NULL`.

Comment: In an earlier version of this post I mistakenly said that the reason for NULL values in DBs was to save memory. It was brought to my attention that this is incorrect and I have updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 3):

Try using the following query:-

```
SELECT  
    Job,  
    Quantity,  
    Status  
FROM  
    myTable 
ORDER BY CASE  
    WHEN QUANTITY >= 400 AND STATUS = 'OK' THEN 1  
    WHEN QUANTITY >= 400 AND STATUS = 'HOLD' THEN 2  
    WHEN QUANTITY <  400 AND STATUS = 'OK' THEN 3  
    WHEN QUANTITY >= 400 AND STATUS = 'HOLD' THEN 4  
    WHEN QUANTITY >= 400 AND COALESCE(STATUS,'') = '' THEN 5  
    WHEN QUANTITY <  400 AND COALESCE(STATUS,'') = '' THEN 6  
END
```

The `COALESCE()` function returns the first non-null argument so if `STATUS` is `NULL` it will return `''`.

http://www.sqlbook.com/SQL/SQL-Coalesce-28.aspx

Comment: +1 because I'd honestly never heard of COALESCE before this post.